# Hoefler Text non-breaking space is too wide

Tags: fonts, typography

In Pages on MacOS, Hoefler Text has very wide non-breaking spaces:

[image: Example]

As you can see, in other fonts, the non-breaking space has the same width as the standard one. In Hoefler Text, it is 3 times wider. This makes the font unusable in french.

The issue is the same on Pages for iOS.

I found very few discussions about this problem — one of them is [here](https://microsoft.public.mac.office.word.narkive.com/eucNqpe9/too-wide-spaces-in-hoefler-text) and it is 17 years old…

Is it a known issue, and does a workaround exist?

Comment: It actually looks like a bug in the font. If you check it in Character Viewer, it's the same width as a regular U+0020 space… but when typed, it doubles its width. All I can think of is some horrible search/replace to another font:\

Comment: A 17 years-old bug in a common character, that is pretty sad… Even more if you know that Hoefler Text was made to showcase advanced type technologies on Macs. Thanks for the search/replace solution, it should work. Maybe I'll use another font…